# It is possible to publish Instagram story from a node.js server to my account? (not a business account)

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I want to publish media files to my Instagram account from a node.js server.

I tried to find a solution in official documentation, but I find only business account solution.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

There is a [content publishing api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing/), but it is available for Instagram partners only - of which social media scheduling tools like Hootsuite are.

The best alternative I've found is that you can use the [Hootsuite API](https://platform.hootsuite.com/docs/api/index.html) to schedule content programatically - but for instagram, this will still require you to use their mobile app to do the actual publishing to Instagram.

Comment: Can we register as Instgram partner? 
Actually, I am creating one app which will post on the user's Instagram account.

Comment: @PuneetUppal: Have you find out any solution, because I have same requirement?

Comment: Are there any updates for this title with the new FB api?